# Subtract first row from all rows in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
a = pd.DataFrame(rand(5,6)*10, index=pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2005', periods=5, freq='A'))
a.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([('A','B'),('a','b','c')])
```

I want to subtract the row `a['2005']` from `a`. To do that I've tried this:

```
In [22]:

a - a.ix['2005']

Out[22]:
    A   B
    a   b   c   a   b   c
2005-12-31  0   0   0   0   0   0
2006-12-31  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2007-12-31  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2008-12-31  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2009-12-31  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Which obviously doesn't work because pandas is lining up the index while doing the operation. This works:

```
In [24]:

pd.DataFrame(a.values - a['2005'].values, index=a.index, columns=a.columns)

Out[24]:
    A   B
    a   b   c   a   b   c
2005-12-31  0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
2006-12-31  -3.326761   -7.164628   8.188518    -0.863177   0.519587    -3.281982
2007-12-31  3.529531    -4.719756   8.444488    1.355366    7.468361    -4.023797
2008-12-31  3.139185    -8.420257   1.465101    -2.942519   1.219060    -5.146019
2009-12-31  -3.459710   0.519435    -1.049617   -2.779370   4.792227    -1.922461
```

But I don't want to have to form a new DataFrame every time I have to do this kind of operation. I've tried the apply() method like this: `a.apply(lambda x: x-a['2005'].values)`
but I get `ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 6 to array axis with dimension 5`
 So I'm not really sure how to proceed. Is there a simple way to do this that I am not seeing? I think there should be an easy way to do this in place so you don't have to construct a new dataframe each time. I also tried the `sub()` method but the subtraction is only applied to the first row whereas I want to subtract the first row from each row in the dataframe.

Comment: Pardon my noobieness, but what exactly do you mean by, "pandas is lining up the index" and why does the first bit of code fail?

Comment: Pandas uses the index "line up" operations in that the operation will apply only to the common indices. So if you want to subtract one row from all in a DataFrame then you need to convert that to a numpy array first as shown in the answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pandas is great for aligning by index. So when you want Pandas to ignore the index, you need to drop the index. You can do that by converting the DataFrame `a.loc['2005']` to a 1-dimensional NumPy array:

```
In [56]: a - a.loc['2005'].values.squeeze()
Out[56]: 
                   A                             B                    
                   a         b         c         a         b         c
2005-12-31  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
2006-12-31  0.325968  1.314776 -0.789328 -0.344669 -2.518857  7.361711
2007-12-31  0.084203  2.234445 -2.838454 -6.176795 -3.645513  8.955443
2008-12-31  3.798700  0.299529  1.303325 -2.770126 -1.284188  3.093806
2009-12-31  1.520930  2.660040  0.846996 -9.437851 -2.886603  6.705391
```

The [`squeeze` method](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html) converts the NumPy array, `a.loc['2005']`, of shape to `(1, 6)` to an array of shape `(6,)`. This allows the array to be broadcasted (during the subtraction) as desired.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. That would explain why `a - a.loc['2005'].values[0]` works as well

Comment: Maybe the word-based ops should grow an `ignore_index` parameter.

Comment: @unutbu You're right, based on what you said the `squeeze` method is a must for this to work. @DSM for some reason I thought this was a default behaviour in earlier versions of pandas. I'm having to rewrite code that was doing the same operations previously like `a - a['2005']`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a more verbose simple break down of how to do this.

First make a simple DataFrame to make it easier to understand.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
#make a simple DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: i+1 , (3, 3), dtype=int))
```

Which will look like this

```
# 1 1 1
# 2 2 2
# 3 3 3
```

Now get the values from the first row

```
first_row = df.iloc[[0]].values[0]
```

Now use apply() to subtract the first row from the rest of the rows.

```
df.apply(lambda row: row - first_row, axis=1)
```

The result will look like this. See that 1 was subtracted from each row

```
#  0 0 0
#  1 1 1
#  2 2 2
```

Answer (score 3):

For timestamp values to calculate how much time passed with respect to the start time use:

```
df['Time_column'].apply(lambda x: x-df.iloc[[0],[1]])
```

Where `df.iloc[[0],[1]]` = the start time

Comment: Thanks - except you'd need to also assign, as .apply is not in-place, so `df['Time_column'] = df['Time_column'].apply...`